# New line for system built-in SMS message in Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-nexus

The built-in SMS application doesn't allow me to enter `new line` as below snapshot. What's wrong with my keyboard :( ?

[image]

Comment: I've also noticed that on several devices. Even if it shows an enter key, that usually *sends* the message instead of inserting a line break. Guess the reason behind is that 160 chars don't require a word processor. Only few draw ASCII art :)

Comment: What if you long-press the enter key?